# Tracking a specific click in an email

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, journeybuilder, automationstudio

I am trying to track (update field in DE) when a subscriber clicks on a link in an email I send.

I'm using a decision split (click tracking) but this feature tracks all links in my email.

How can I just track one Link?  I guess I have to use a Query but don't know where to start.

Once the subscriber clicked the link and the mentioned field is updated, we want to shoot another email. But with Automation Studio or Journey Builder I can't do this as far as I know.

How can I send an email the moment a field when a Data Extension is updated?

Answer (score 1):

Journey Builder can do this.

Add the Engagement Split Activity to your canvas after the email, select the 'Click' Message metric and then select the link within the email that you want to track.

You can then add the Update Contact Data Activity and the subsequent email Activity, so your Journey will look something like this:

[image: journey]

Comment: I don't see that option to select by a specific link in my Engagement Split.  I see this: "Selecting individual links is not supported for this email. Click Done to monitor all links in the email. Learn More" - clicking on the Learn More link leads to a broken page: http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/canvas_activities/use-the-engagement-decision-activity

Comment: Refer to second answer below. The only solution I can think of for classic emails is to write a query and use the [Click Data View](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/data_view_click/) to save the results to a DE. Include this query activity in a Scheduled Automation, then use a Decision Split in your Interaction to check whether the Contact clicked on a link (by evaluating the DE containing click data).

Answer (score 1):

The option is only available for emails built using the new Content Builder.